# Problem of application of HashTable in Fibonacci

Tags: recursion, data-structures

As we can see the example in `ref/datastructure/HashTable`

[image]

This code show the usage of HashTable,
Fib is the implement of Fibonacci Number with HashTable.

If we subtle adjust the value, for example `Fib[1200]` on my computer, we can find this problem:

`Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation`

How can I make this version `Fib` useful[practical] like the plain memorization version?
without modify $RecursionLimit if possible.

`f1[1]=1; f1[2]=1; f1[n_]:=f1[n]=f1[n-1]+f1[n-2]`

What's the benefits of `HashTable` in this example? Slower and Limited?

[image]

Comment: There are no real benefits to this vs. the memoization. This is a toy example, a form of memoizing manually, but it trips the recursion limit. To see why, put this `Print["looked up Fib[" <> ToString[n] <> "]"];` just before the `st["Lookup",n]`. Memoization still has to recurse, just not as much as the naive approach. Try `f1[1200]` - you still trip the limit even with that plain method.